# Parse XML error in VBScript

Tags: xml, parsing, vbscript, xml-parsing

I have this simple `VBScript` that sends an `HTTP POST` request and reads the returning `HTML` response.

```
Function httpPOST(url, body, username, password )  
  Set Http = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")   
  Http.Open "POST", url, False, username, password  
  Http.setRequestHeader _  
              "Content-Type", _  
              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
  Http.send body 
  pagestatus = Http.status
  if pagestatus<> "200" then
    httpPOST="Error:"& pagestatus
  else
    'httpPOST = Http.ResponseBody
    'httpPOST = Http.responseText
    Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
    objXMLDoc.async = False
    objXMLDoc.validateOnParse = False
    objXMLDoc.load(Http.ResponseBody)
    Set objNode = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("/html/body/center/img")
    httpPost = objNode.getAttribute("alt") 
  end if
End Function
```

The `HTML` response format is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>---</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <img alt="You are now connected" src="pages/GEN/connected_gen.png">
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue with this script is that it always returns `Error: Object required: 'objNode'`

I have tried so many variations of `XML` parsers, and finally gave up for every time I got the same error related to `XML` objects.

Comment: Does it work when you try loading it from file and not from web? Are you sure html does not have any xmlns defined?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error either if I try to read the xml locally or from the web. This html was copied as is from the view-source of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167329/603855): `.load` expects 'A string containing a URL that specifies the location of the XML file'; so use .loadXml to check whether `Http.ResponseBody`
contains data that `MSXML?.DOMDocument` can parse (your second problem).

**UPDATE:**

Something that 'works' (and why):

```
  Dim sHTML : sHTML = readAllFromFile("..\data\02.html")
  WScript.Echo sHTML
  Dim oXDoc : Set oXDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  oXDoc.async = False
  oXDoc.validateOnParse = False
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  If oXDoc.loadXML(sHTML) Then
     Dim ndImg : Set ndImg = oXDoc.selectSingleNode("/html/body/center/img")
     Dim httpPost : httpPost = ndImg.getAttribute("alt")
     WScript.Echo "ok", httpPost
  Else
     WScript.Echo "Error: " & trimWS(oXDoc.parseError.reason)
  End If
```

output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>---</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <img alt="You are now connected" src="pages/GEN/connected_gen.png"/>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>

ok You are now connected
```

**MSXML2.DOMDocument** will `.loadXML` (and parse) HTML code, provided it is 'XML-valid'. Your HTML isn't, because the img tag is not closed - the error message I got for your original code:

```
Error: End tag 'center' does not match the start tag 'img'.
```

How to proceed further depends on whether you are able/willing to change the HTML.

**UPDATE II:**

While you could do nasty things to .ResponseBody **before** you feed it to .loadXML - why not use a HTML tool to parse HTML:

```
  Dim sHTML : sHTML = readAllFromFile("..\data\01.html")
  WScript.Echo sHTML
  Dim oHF : Set oHF = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
  oHF.write sHTML
  Dim httpPost : httpPost = oHF.documentElement.childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(0).alt
  WScript.Echo "ok", httpPost
```

output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>---</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <img alt="You are now connected" src="pages/GEN/connected_gen.png">
        </center>
    </body>
</html>

ok You are now connected
```

As the output shows, HTMLFILE accepts your 'not-xml-closed' img; the method to get what you really want should be sanitized, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said in my question I tried so many variations, and the link you posted was one of them. I think you are referring to `Msxml2.DOMDocument` not `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP`. It might end up to what you pointed as my second problem.

Comment: @update: Technically speaking the html is valid, the img tag is closed. It might be a parser issue. Do you know any other one that I can use, because I do not have control over html response.

Comment: @update ii: works just fine. this is what I ended up doing, thanks for your help.